# testdriven.io: The Definitive Guide to Celery and Django. Running task from Django shell causes error

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, celery, testdriven.io

I am currently going through 'The Definitive Guide to Celery and Django' course by testdriven.io. I've managed to containerize the whole application. Everything was built correctly and seemed to work just fine, but when I tried to enter the Django shell and run a task, to ensure everything works correctly, the following error appeared.

```
>>> divide.delay(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 30, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 446, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 312, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 877, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 812, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 201, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 129, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 184, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 425, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 575, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 788, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 510, in send_task_message
    ret = producer.publish(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 177, in publish
    return _publish(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 523, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 186, in _publish
    channel = self.channel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 209, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 32, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 225, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 895, in default_channel
    self._ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 432, in _ensure_connection
    with ctx():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 450, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    raise ConnectionError(str(exc)) from exc
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I've done a quick research and in most cases it seemed to be a lack of the following lines

```
from config.celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

in the `config.__init__.py`, but it's clearly not an issue here.
I also double checked whether redis container is up and listening on port 6379.
The only difference between my code and the course code is that I decided to use Poetry package manager instead of requirements.txt file and pip.

At this point I am a little bit confused I'll be thankful for any tip. You can find the whole code below:
`https://github.com/Kibraks/django-celery-app`